# Calcular frete dos correios para diversos produtos

Tags: matemática, web-service

Estou tentando fazer o cálculo do frete de diversos produtos utilizando o [WebService dos correios](http://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/correios-de-a-a-z/pdf/calculador-remoto-de-precos-e-prazos/manual-de-implementacao-do-calculo-remoto-de-precos-e-prazos), porém estou com dúvidas/dificuldade para efetuar o cálculo quando tenho diversos produtos.

> Estou utilizando o código em PHP para chamar o webservice e receber o retorno em XML. Essa chamada está correta. Consigo chamar e receber os valores corretamente. Minha dúvida é mais na lógica de como calcular e processar quando possuo um carrinho de compras com mais de um produto.

Sei que devo me atentar ao cálculo com base nas dimensões (altura, largura, comprimento e peso), também sei que nesse caso o cálculo é feito com base em peso cúbico, [conforme documentação](http://www.correios.com.br/para-sua-empresa/comercio-eletronico/como-calcular-precos-e-prazos-de-entrega-em-sua-loja-on-line).

Porém os parâmetros que devo preencher para efetuar o cálculo não disponibilizam um campo para enviar mais de um produto. Neste caso, como deve ser feito o cálculo?

Faço o somatório das dimensões de modo "bruto"? Ex.: 2 produtos de dimensões:

- A: 10cm, L: 15cm, C: 22cm
- A: 8cm, L: 31cm, C: 18cm
- Total: A: 18cm, L: 46cm, C: 40cm

E envio esses somatórios?

Quando faço isso até consigo obter o resultado, porém não me parece certo, sendo que algumas vezes a diferença do frete é muito grande. Ex.:

- Frete produto A: R$18,00
- Frete produto B: R$21,00
- Frete somatório A+B: R$88,00

Alguém tem experiência com esse tipo de serviço que possa me ajudar?

---

Para facilitar o entendimento, os dados referente ao(s) produto(s) que o webservice dos correios recebem são:

- **nVlPeso**: ex.: 4 (para 4Kg);
- **nVlComprimento**: ex.: 10 (para 10cm);
- **nVlAltura**: ex.: 15 (para 15cm);
- **nVlLargura**: ex.: 20 (para 20cm);
- **nVlDiametro**: *não obrigatório

Não existe, por exemplo, uma opção de mais de um item, apenas esses dados.

Comment: O melhor é tentar montar em 3D (ou 2D para efeitos didáticos)  como ficaria o produto junto. Você vai ver que somar nas três dimensões é ter muito espaço vazio

Comment: Está utilizando embalagens dos correios ou própria?

Comment: @Randrade A princípio utilizando apenas embalagem própria. Alguns produtos já tem a embalagem de fábrica.

Comment: O que acontece quando o produto já possui embalagem própria? Você agruparia em uma única embalagem ou enviaria em embalagens distintas?

Comment: @Randrade é difícil responder, pois depende um pouco. Alguns casos da pra só "Amarrar", ou, por exemplo, embrulhar com papel pardo. Alguns, pelo que vi, não passam pelas regras dos correios, então teria que ser embalagens distintas. Já outros são pequenos e da pra botar diversos em apenas uma caixa.

Comment: @Randrade para por em contexto, são produtos de petshop. Desde medicamentos, brinquedos, sacos de ração (1,3,5,10kg), etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depois de algum tempo lendo **muito** material online e pesquisando exaustivamente sobre o assunto, acho que consegui chegar a um resultado satisfatório.

Como já discutido aqui (e também uma questão referente no meta) sei que o empacotamento 2D ou 3D vai ser algo extremamente difícil (ou impossível), mas, como dito na questão, minha dúvida maior se dava ao fato de como calcular o frete para um ou mais produtos de modo que não seja feito uma das seguintes propostas:

- Somatório de `Frete A` + `Frete B`;
- Somatório das medidas do `Produto A` + `Produto B` e cálculo do frete;

Outro problema encontrado foi de como adicionar as informações de diversos produtos sendo que o `webservice` dos Correios aceita apenas um valor para cada um dos campos.

Deste modo eu consegui chegar a um cálculo onde, até o momento, eu acredito que esteja retornando valores muito mais próximos aos valores reais do frete do que com o método usado anteriormente.

> Observação: Não cheguei a testar oficialmente efetuando o cálculo pelo código e verificando no balcão dos Correios no momento de enviar o produto.

---

A lógica por trás do cálculo é a seguinte:

- Calcular o valor em `cm³` para cada produto (Largura x Altura x Comprimento x Quantidade);
- Somar o valor de `cm³` e peso de todos os produtos;
- Extração da raiz cúbica do somatório de `cm³` de todos os produtos;

Para esses cálculos, estou utilizando este código:

```php
$total_peso = 0;
$total_cm_cubico = 0;

/**
 * $produto = lista de produtos no carrinho de compras. Deve possuir,
 * obrigatoriamente, os campos largura, altura, comprimento e quantidade.
 */
foreach ($produto as $row) {
    $row_peso = $row['peso'] * $row['quantidade'];
    $row_cm = ($row['altura'] * $row['largura'] * $row['comprimento']) * $row['quantidade'];

    $total_peso += $row_peso;
    $total_cm_cubico += $row_cm;
}

$raiz_cubica = round(pow($total_cm_cubico, 1/3), 2);
$resposta = array(
    'total_peso' => $total_peso,
    'raiz_cubica' => $raiz_cubica,
);
```

Deste modo, no momento de preencher os dados a serem enviados ao serviço dos Correios, eu preencho da seguinte maneira:

```php
// Os valores 16, 2, 11 e 0.3 são os valores mínimos determinados pelo serviço dos Correios
$comprimento =  $raiz_cubica < 16 ? 16 : $raiz_cubica;
$altura = $raiz_cubica < 2 ? 2 : $raiz_cubica;
$largura = $raiz_cubica < 11 ? 11 : $raiz_cubica;
$peso = $total_peso < 0.3 ? 0.3 : $total_peso;
$diametro = hypot($comprimento, $largura); // Calculando a hipotenusa pois minhas encomendas são retangulares

'nVlPeso'        => $peso,
'nVlComprimento' => $comprimento,
'nVlAltura'      => $altura,
'nVlLargura'     => $largura,
'nVlDiametro'    => $diametro, // não obrigatório
```

Com esse cálculo eu consegui atingir resultados onde calculando o valor do frete individual de 2 produtos eu obtive os valores:

- Produto A: R$17,10
- Produto B: R$20,40

E ao executar dos dois produtos juntos obtive R$23,60 (considerando que pelas medidas e tipo de pacote não consegui valor inferior à R$17,10 - deve ser taxa mínima).

Esse tipo de resultado se repetiu (de modo semelhante) em diversos produtos diferentes e quantidades diferentes, ou seja, não houve soma de fretes e sim um aumento gradativo conforme as medidas e peso dos produtos.

Lembrando que há algumas funcionalidades pendentes, como a validação das medidas para que não ultrapasse os valores máximos e, caso ultrapasse, dividir o frete em mais de uma "caixa".

Comment: sensacional! Eu tinha chegado na fórmula da raiz cúbica mas não tinha pensado na hipotenusa desse valor, estranho a api deles considerar o diâmetro se a requisição considera que a embalagem é uma caixa. Independente disso funcionou num primeiro teste em que o produto tinha 50x25x98cm e 10.740kg. Vou adicionar um log no nosso sistema pra salvar as requisições com essa fórmula proposta e comparar os resultados (teste A/B) pra ver como ficam. Hoje na verdade utilizamos só a soma dos pesos e funciona pra maioria dos casos

Answer (score 22):

## Sobre o empacotamento

O principal ponto de dificuldade que vi em sua questão foi na hora de enviar as dimensões do pacote. Vou fazer em 2D para simplificar.

Imagine que você quer enviar dois Açúcar União:

[image: açúcar união]

Ele tem dimensão dois dedos por cinco dedos, para 5g de conteúdo:

| [image: dois dedos] | [image: cinco dedos] |
| --- | --- |

Somar as dimensões do jeito que você estava fazendo era fazer assim:

[image: pondo de maneira equivocada]

Ou então assim:

[image: pondo de maneira equivocada 2]

Na primeira maneira equivocada, dos 49 dedos quadrados (7 dedos por 7 dedos) do pacote, apenas 20 dedos quadrados de fato estão sendo usados. Note o quadrado sem nada maior de 25 dedos quadrados, e o menor de 4 dedos quadrados.

No segundo empacotamento, a área total é de 40 dedos quadrados (4 dedos por 10 dedos). Note que, para cada pacote de 10 dedos quadrados, tem uma área vazia logo do lado de mesmo tamanho.

Os melhores empacotamentos para você seriam:

[image: 4 dedos por 5 dedos]

Ou esse:

[image: 2 dedos por 10 dedos]

Eu não sei se os correios de quadradônia levam em consideração a área apenas, ou se levam em consideração as dimensões individuais. Eu perguntaria para o webservice dos correios de quadradônia ambas as opções se pudesse mandar essas requisições.

Agora, imagina que você deseja enviar um Açúcar União é um Sal Sosal:

[image: sosal]

O Sal tem medidas 2 dedos por 3 dedos para 1g (medidas didáticas e aproximadas, não vou postar a foto aqui).

Então, você pode empacotar dessas quatro maneiras o açúcar e o sal:

| 4x5 | 5x5 | 8x2 | 7x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: 4 por 5] | [image: 5 por 5] | [image: 8 por 2] | [image: 7 por 3] |

Veja que 5x5 não é a melhor escolha, ele é 100% dominado por 4x5 em todas as dimensões consideradas. Agora, 8x2 tem área total de 16 dedos quadrados, sendo uma opção de menor área total do que 4x5.

> Mais tarde eu coloco um algoritmo de como fazer esse empacotamento em 2D, mas creio que para 3D ou dimensões superiores seja muito diferente

Comment: Pois é.. Uma alternativa seria um cálculo mais complexo (presumo eu). Identificar o produto de maior dimensão, ex.: Altura, e somar somente os demais valores. Não seria o ideal, mas seria melhor do que esse método de "empacotamento" que tenho. A ideia do seu método eu consigo compreender, mas não sei como aplicar isso de modo que o seja efetuado o cálculo corretamente. Inclusive atualizei a questão para mostrar os dados que o WebService recebe.

Comment: `Mais tarde eu coloco um algoritmo de como fazer esse empacotamento em 2D` Boa sorte, pois esse problema é NP completo.

Comment: Como é um algoritmo de busca (mais especificamente busca para enumeração, não busca para contagem), não algoritmo de decisão, ele não cabe exatamente na classificação em P/NP ou outra classe de complexidade convencional (como RE ou PSPACE ou AM). Também não prometi eficiência. E a estratégia que estou usando é mais semelhante a EXPTIME do que NP.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa somar apenas uma dimensão, por exemplo altura, e pegar o valor maior das outras duas.

A: 10cm, L: 15cm, C: 22cm

A: 8cm, L: 31cm, C: 18cm

Total: A: 18cm, L: 31cm, C: 22cm

Suponha que empacote uma caixa em cima da outra. A altura será somada, mas a largura máxima e o comprimento máximo permanecem os mesmos.
Somando tudo, como no raciocínio inicial, se eleva ao cubo o volume dos produtos. Em vez de calcular os 2 pacotes, estaria calculando o volume de 8 pacotes.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/154593)

Comment: Me desculpe, mas responde sim. Indica a lógica correta e simplifica o caminho da solução apresentada até então que, no meu entender, dá voltas desnecessárias.
Também gostaria que esclarecesse a razão de minha resposta depender de mais informações de quem perguntou, não entendi.
Só postei porque seria uma referencia útil para quem consultasse a questão no futuro, mas se fere alguma regra do site, podem excluir sem problemas.

Comment: Eu já havia testado desse modo, infelizmente, os resultados não eram próximos ao que se esperava. A diferença de valores ao somar os fretes é muito alta. Acredito que um dos motivos para isso seja o fato de que o calculo do frete, por parte dos correios, leva em consideração o m³, conforme exposto em um link na questão.

Comment: @user105586 , a lógica para isso está na melhor das hipóteses incompleta. Isso se aplica a dois produtos, mas para 3 ou mais produtos a situação é distinta, pois o formato de sólido côncavo advindo do empacotamento de 2 paralelepípedos permite encaixar mais sólidos no meio. E também tem o problema do empilhamento (já que alguns produtos não podem ser empilhados por serem frágeis)

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, ressuscitando defunto, rsrsrsrs mas vou postar minha contribuição q pode ser que ajude alguém no futuro.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema pra uma empresa de produtos naturais, eles tem chás, encapsulados produtos solúveis.. bem variado. Consegui resolver essa dificuldade convertendo a medida de cada produto para cm³(centímetro cúbico Altura x Largura x Comprimento)
Depois somo a medida de cada produto.
Ao final tiro a raiz quadrada do resultado e passo como altura, largura e comprimento.
Bateu certinho

Exemplo:
produto com c15 a13 l8 então esse produto tem 1560cm³ se mandar 3 unidades serão 4680m³
outro produto com c20 15 l13 ele terá 1300cm³ mandando 2 unidades serão 2600m³

somando os dois subtotais chegamos a 7280 a raiz cubica dele é 19.38, como a caixa sempre é maior que o volume de produtos, eu acrescentei 10% a esse valor que dá o valor de 21,32 cm.
Então faço o calculo sobre 21,32 de altura, 21,32 de largura e 21,32 de comprimento.

obs coloquei um IF para cada medida para atender o padrão mínimo dos correios. Por exemplo se o resultado for menor que 2, a variável da altura vai receber o valor de 2 que é a altura mínima exigida pelo correio.

Espero que ajude caso alguém.